# iTunes Audio Book won't play in CD player

Tags: itunes, audiobook

I just bought an audio book on iTunes, and I'd like to listen to it in my car. I created a playlist that contained the audio book, and burned an audio CD. When I put the CD in my car, it just ejects the CD.

When I explore the CD, I see that there is a .cda file present on the disk. Is this the correct format?

What can I do to get the book to play in my car's CD player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be unable to burn Audio Books to a CD due to DRM encrypted purchases.

Comment: How do I know if it's DRM encrypted or not? Nothing is mentioned of it on the iTunes store where I bought it, but it does say that the file is protected if I try to convert it to AAC. I thought iTunes wasn't doing that anymore.

This doesn't do me any good if I can't play it in a CD player.

Comment: If it's "protected" then you probably can't convert it. I don't know if they let you burn them to CD's anymore either. I get all my music DRM free.

Answer (score 2):

Do other burned CDs work in your car?  Some older stereos tend to reject CD-Rs or CD-RWs.  Additionally, check out [The Red Book Audio CD standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_(audio_Compact_Disc_standard)).  If your CD breaks any of the five specifications listed there, it may not play in your typical CD player.

Comment: Mine won't play a CD-R and manual specifically mentions this will not work.